# Is there an C way to read txt file string by string?

Tags: c, file, input

I have stuck in writing a "reading" loop in C.

### What I want:

I want to do something like in C++:

```
std::ifstream input("input.txt");
std::string myString;
while(input>>myString)
{
do_sth;
}
```

### What I have:

I have read a lot of posts in that forum but everywhere I saw: 
1. Reading line by line and then cut lines into strings 
2. Read char by char and merge there into string 
and others like that:

```
const int maxStrLen=40;
char str[maxStrLen];
while(!feof(fp))
{
fgets(str,maxStrLen,fp);
}
```

Is there possibile to read .txt file string by string? Have somebody any idea?

Comment: Moderator, you have pasted link to different problem, read the post again and then make a decision.

Comment: Nearly impossible. C isn't powerful enough. Only a super-programmer could create a function library in C to do something like this. I'm not sure it can be done... :-)

Comment: @RobertHarvey - I think you misunderstood the question. OP isn't looking to read the file line-by-line. He wants to read a "string" (delimited, one supposes, by something other than `\n`), process it, then read another string. I respectfully submit that this question is not a dupe of the cited question.

Comment: Read more about [parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing)

Comment: @BobJarvis: C is a Turing-complete language.  The only thing that might prevent this from happening is programmer apathy or not enough coffee.

Comment: @BobJarvis Chmm, If it comes to creating a lib in C to do something like this, it would be bigger than my actual project (I want to do some transformations on txt file in C). In that case the best option would be read some chars into tab (and count them because string can have different length) while don't meet space and then merge first n chars into "string" and pass it to my function

Comment: Sounds like you've made a good start. Keep at it! :-)

Comment: Ok, thanks for response @BobJarvis ;)

Comment: fscanf %s reads a string. However, unless you have a strict upper bound for the length of string, your core problem is actually implementing (or choosing a library for) dynamic string handling.

Comment: All 20k words are in one line so...

Comment: @hyde: If you're using POSIX (pretty much anything except MS), `fscanf("%ms"`... does the trick nicely